# How To Log TLS Mutual Authentication Details?

Tags: apache-2.2, nginx, haproxy, tls

Is there a way to log the low-level details of the TLS mutual authentication flow (most importantly - the challenge that is sent to the client and the signed response).

Solution for any tool is welcome: nginx, Apache (mod_proxy), HAProxy, etc.